# Solving a Gaussian-like integral in polar coordinates

Tags: definite-integrals, gaussian-integral, fubini-tonelli-theorems

I want to solve this Gaussian-like integral

$$ I =\int_0^1 e^{-x^2} \mathrm dx \tag{1} $$

This integral may be solved by considering x as a dummy variable and applying the Fubini's theorem to transform it into a double integral as follows:

$$ I =\int_0^1 e^{-y^2} \mathrm dy \tag{2} $$

$$ I^2 =\left(\int_0^1 e^{-x^2} \mathrm dx\right)\left(\int_0^1 e^{-y^2} \mathrm dy\right) = \int_0^1\int_0^1 e^{-\left(x^2+y^2\right)} \mathrm dx \mathrm dy \tag{3} $$

Here is when things get a bit interesting. The double integral may be solved by a variable change to polar coordinates:

$$ I^2 = \int_0^{\frac{\pi}{2}}\int_0^R e^{-r^2} \mathrm r \mathrm dr \mathrm d\theta \tag{4} $$

The above integral should yield the following result:

$$ I^2 = \frac{\pi}{4} \bigg[\text{erf}\left(1\right)\bigg]^2 \tag{5} $$

Or:

$$ I = \frac{\sqrt\pi}{2} \text{erf}\left(1\right) \tag{6} $$

Now comes my inquiry: I have not managed to figure out how to transform the integration region in (3) so I may find an appropriate value of R for which the integral result is (6). By doing some calculations, i.e., by making (4) = (5), finding the integral and solving for R, I found that:

$$ R = \sqrt{-\text{ln}\bigg[1-\left(\text{erf}\left(1\right)\right)^2\bigg]} \tag{7}  $$

Is there an analytical (inductive/non-trial-and-error) procedure to find R as in (7) from a transformation of the integration region in (3) to polar coordinates? I will be most grateful if anyone can help me figure this puzzle.

Comment: The region you are integrating over is a square, that cannot be written as one integral in polar coordinates unless you use symmetry.

Comment: @NinadMunshi Is there any possibility to make such a symmetry approximation?

Answer (score 0):

This is perhaps more of a comment than an answer, because I'm not exactly sure what you're asking.  Just by drawing a picture, we have $$R(\theta)=\cases{
\frac1{\cos\theta},&$0\leq\theta\leq\frac\pi4$\\
\frac1{\sin\theta},&$\frac\pi4\leq\theta\leq\frac\pi2$\\
}$$
but you seem to be asking for an $R$ that doesn't depend on $\theta$.

**EDIT**

[image]

Comment: Well, in fact I want to know how to transform a square region in rectangular coordinates (the one shown in equation (3)) to polar coordinates so that the integration interval in r goes from 0 to the value of R shown in equation (7), which is the upper limit of the integral with respect to r in polar coordinates (equation (4)). Hope this clears your doubts.

Comment: However, I am now curious about how did you obtain the R(θ) equation.

Comment: @inghans Look at the picture I added.  $R=\frac1{\cos\theta}$  When $\theta >\frac\pi4$, you have to draw a triangle using the side of the square on the $y$-axis.

Comment: Oh, I think I got it. So the solution may involve separating the double integral into two. In that case, how may we rewrite equation (4) properly?

Comment: @inghans Write the right-hand side as the sum of two integrals, one where $0\leq y\leq \pi/4$ and one where $\pi/4\leq y\leq\pi/2$

Comment: Sure, I will. But in that case, there is no need to apply the Fubini's theorem or transform the integral into polar coordinates using the Jacobian as I did because the region area is $ \frac{1}{2} \text{r}^2 \mathrm d\theta $ instead of $ \mathrm r \mathrm d \mathrm r \mathrm d\mathrm \theta $ and so we get two integrals with respect to $ \theta $ (or y, in your case). Am I right about this?

Comment: @inghans I don't think so.  We're just describing the region in polar coordinates, as usual.

Comment: Later, I will show something I found in Math Stack Exchange.